# how to to make responsive dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the same menu as in the [doordash](https://www.doordash.com/store/hot-woks-cool-sushi-chicago-23308/) website. I am almost done, but the problem is in the more button. How can I put the extra items in a slide panel when changing the screen resolution?

For example, while narrowing the browser window, the items in the dropdown menu increase and while widening the browser window, the items in the drop down menu decrease.

In other words, the menu contains 3 items onload(wide screen), and on mobile screen size will contain 6 items.

Html:

```
  <div class="MoreCategoriesContainer" style="display:none">
 <button class="extraCategorylist">food1</button>
 <button class="extraCategorylist">food2</button>
 <button class="extraCategorylist">food3</button>
 <button class="extraCategorylist">food4</button>
 <button class="extraCategorylist">food5</button>
 <button class="extraCategorylist">food6</button> </div>
```

All css I have for the dropdown menu is:

```
.MoreCategoriesContainer {
overflow-y: auto;
 max-height: 80vh;
 position: absolute;
  right: 0;
   top: calc(100% + 2px);
 box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.19);
  border-radius: 4px;
 background: #fff;
 padding: 6px 24px;
 }
```

Comment: Use media queries to set `display: none` to the item's which supposed not to be on the wide screen

Comment: Its too much to add display: none for every item!

Comment: any answer plz?

Answer (score 1):

Set class to `large-hidden` for items that you don't want to display on the large screen, and use the following css rules:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 830px) {
    .large-hidden {
       display: none;
    }
}
```